# What is the best way to run an Ubuntu server on Windows with Docker and develop with an IDE?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, virtual-machine, containers

I am trying to switch from developing in an Ubuntu VM to using Docker but don't want to be confined to command-line applications/editors etc. Is there a way I can use Docker to run my Ubuntu server with NodeJS/Rails/etc while editing my application code in Windows using an IDE, or at the very least a text editor like Sublime? I spend most of my time in Windows and wish I could just stay in the same environment while developing web applications.

Comment: Better use case for Vagrant than Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to Docker Machine: https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Here you have instructions to get started with Docker Machine and a local VM: https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/

Comment: So I read through those links and I don't really understand. I already have Docker installed and can spin up an Ubuntu container. Is the filesystem of that machine accessible within Windows? The main thing I want to figure out is how to integrate it with an IDE so I can actually do my development in Windows rather than being stuck with say VIM.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mapped volume for your source code.   Edit file in windows/whatever, run code in docker.  Done.

See the Mount a host directory... [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)